# Creating polygons with Geodesic measurements?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, polygon, arcgis-pro

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.9 to translate plats into GIS. I've begun to notice some measuring inconsistencies.

Having projected in WGS 1984 World Mercator, I would expect when I create polygons they would measure in geodesic, yet they do not.

How do I create polygons that measure in geodesic?

Comment: It's not possible for Mercator to measure distances correctly. If you need geodesic measurement, you should use geodesic functions.

Comment: I have never heard that Mercator cannot measure distances correctly. What do you mean, @Vince? Any sort of elucidation would be appreciated! Unfortunately  I'm running some code in GIS currently and cannot add a screenshot of what occurs.

Comment: That's pretty much what Mercator is famous (infamous) 
for -- Conformal, yes; straight lines of constant bearing, yes; accurate distance, heck no. Global cylindrical projections treat the poles as a line and therefore mangle distance. Mercator all the more so because the poles are infinitely far from the Equator. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/mercator.htm

Comment: @Vince thanks, much more straightforward!! I remember this a bit now from grad school a few hundred years ago. 

Too bad every time I notice someone asks a "basic" question they get down-voted to hell. Sometimes it's the little things that we get hung up on.

Answer (score 0):

I created a process to insert Geodesic polygons in Mercator using lines and the buffer tool:

- Select the Insert tab-> Measurements group-> Distance and Direction. Then ensure that the line type is geodesic, and that the distance/length is what you need.
- Use a Buffer Tool, I like the Pairwise Buffer to dissolve features into one polygon, and then Merge the polygon(s) into your wanted layer.
- Edit the polygon(s) as needed.